# How to get CPU-G to run on Debian 10?

Tags: debian, package-management, python

GPU-G is a linux alternative to CPU-Z on Windows (apparently) but I can't get it to run.

When I run `python2 ./gpu-g` I get the following error

```
You need to have PyGTK 2.10.0, GTK.Glade and GTK+ 2.10.0 or higher
installed in your system in order to run CPU-G.
```

I tried installing `pip` with the intention of trying to find those packages, as I could not find them with `apt`, but this gave me a python 3 version of pip.

Not sure what to try next?

Answer (score 1):

CPU-G is a python 3 application.

The instructions to run it are published here: https://github.com/atareao/cpu-g

In short:

```
sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev gcc libcairo2-dev pkg-config python3-dev gir1.2-gtk-3.0
pip3 install pycairo PyGObject psutil dbus-python
git clone https://github.com/atareao/cpu-g.git
cd cpu-g/bin
python3 cpu-g
```

Comment: I edited your answer - did I get the correction correct?

Comment: It may need to be approved?

Comment: Regardless of edits - there is no file `cpu-g` in that directory

Comment: @user3728501 there definitely is: `$ ls cpu-g/bin/cpu-g 
cpu-g/bin/cpu-g`

Comment: Sorry I was looking in src not bin